# How to create parent groups in Gitblit?

Tags: git, gitblit

We are trying to create new groups and fix typos i.e.*Group 3* vs *group 3* in our groups in Gitblit and have already tried editing the `projects.conf` file with no success.  [Documentation is sparse online](https://code.google.com/p/gitblit/).

What other setup/configuration files can we edit to add new project groups?

See screenshot below.[image]

Comment: I try to create a new group too. Did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an account with admin right to create a new group.
When you create a new repository, choose the projet "/" and add the name "GroupeName/RepositoryName". It will create a new group with the name GroupName and add the new repository inside it.

[image]